# Dynamically execute functions in different folders using bash

Tags: bash, sh

I have two folders: `control` and `patients` both with several folders inside, belonging to one `individual` each.

I want to do two things:

- Create inside the folder for each individual a new folder called `cortical_maks` and inside that one, three more, called `accumebens, putamen, caudate`
- Inside each individual folder, there are images in `img` format I want to convert to `nii.gz` using the funtion `fslchfiletype`.

This is what I have so far:

```
DIR="/media/Roy"; cd "$DIR/Analysis"
for group in Controls Patients; do
    for case in $group/*; do
        [ -d $case ] || continue #if its not a folder
        mkdir $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks  && cd $_
        mkdir accumbens putamen caudate
            
        for file in $DIR/Analysis/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi/*.img; do
        fslchfiletype NIFTI_GZ "$file"
        done;
    done;
done;
```

There are two problems with this code.

- The second time you run it, the folder `cortical masks` is created in the main folders, that is `controls`  and `patients`, that is, outside the folder it´s supposed to work.
- Also, it just converts `img` to `niig.gz` for one folder at a time. First time you execute the script, converts imgs for the folder belonging to the first individual, etc

Comment: Try pasting your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 01 :

*The second time you run it, the folder cortical masks is created in the main folders, that is controls  and patients. I want it in a way that doesn´t create new folders if there is already one with the same name.*

I suggest you to use an if loop to verify if the folder cortical_mask exist before to run your code :

```
#check if the folder exist, if yes = true so we add ! caracter to have the opposite
if [ ! -d "$DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks" ] 
then
      #Your code
fi
```

Question 02 :

*Also, it just converts img to niig.gz for one folder at a time. First time you execute the script, converts imgs for the folder belonging to the first individual, etc*

If you want to do two actions in the same time, why do you not create two bash scripts and execute them simulteanously ? Or, you can automate them by creating a process in your OS which will execute scripts for you.